# Order of Ant Task Arguments

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm new to Ant and wrote up a simple build.xml with some help yesterday. However after looking at the output from running ant -verbose it appears as if a class I have to handle many JUnit tests isn't being called appropriately.

```
<project name="JUnit_tests" default="run" basedir=".">

<!-- Define variable properties -->
<property name="src" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="junit" value="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"/>

<!--<property name="junit" value="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"/>-->

<!-- Appends all jars in the current directory to the classpath -->
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="./">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- Compiles all code in the current directory and append to the classpath -->
<target name="compile">
    <javac destdir="${src}" srcdir="${src}">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- Runs the Test code with junit argument as long as compile was run previously -->
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="Tests" fork="true">
        <arg value="${junit}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

My JUnit tests are in the Tests class, and I need to run the class with

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tests
```

However based on the following output I believe it's being called as

```
java Tests org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

Ant -verbose output:

```
run:
     [java] Executing '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java' with arguments:
     [java] 'Tests'
     [java] 'org.junit.runner.JUnitCore'
     [java] 
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

Any ideas? I've been doing research but couldn't find much about the order of arguments, specifically with a java call. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have interverted your argument (which is `Tests`) and the main class which is `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`.

`<arg>` are the arguments of the program
`<jvmarg>` are the arguments of the JVM

In between the two of them, you will have the main class.

Java usage:

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]

In your case, you want to execute the main method of `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` and the arguments passed to that main method should be `Tests`